# String separation and column filtering to new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, filtering

Hei, I'm quite new using SQL server and I'm looking for some help. I have to extract value 'Lab' from ParLab in TableA. I need some help with filtering from only the codes from 'Lab' that begin with 'L' and from 'Mcode' the ones that are equal to '9LL' and '2AN'.

```
 TableA 

 ParLab  Mcode  Entry
 L;58    9LL    948487
 L;58    2AN    e@y.com
 L;80    9LL    938745
 L;58    3B2    563467
 T;80    2AN    d@g.com
 T;88    9LL    827120
 T;88    9LL    k@g.com
 A;7;2   2AN    928233
```

Then I have to join on 'Lab' from TableB on the values separated from the string ParLab that correspond to 'Lab'.

```
 TableB

 Lab        Customer
 58         Lynn
 80         Laurence
 88         Emmanuel
```

I have used this code to separate the string:

```
  SELECT ParLab, MCode, Entry
        ,SUBSTRING(ParLab,CHARINDEX(';', ParLab)+1, LEN(ParLab)) AS Lab

  FROM TableA
```

The result should contain  Tel and Email in different columns assigned to 'Lab' and Customer joined  to TableB on 'Lab'.

```
  Customer  Lab  Tel      Email
  Lynn      58   948487   e@y.com
  Laurence  80   938745   d@g.com
  Emmanuel  88   827120   k@g.com
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server version is 15.0.18142

Comment: Probably `STRING_SPLIT(ParLab, ';')`  is also an option here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This below

```
DECLARE @TableA  AS TABLE ( ParLab  VARCHAR(100), Mcode VARCHAR(100),  Entry VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TableA
SELECT 'L;58' ,'9LL','948487'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'L;58' ,'2AN','e@y.com'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'L;80' ,'9LL','938745'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'L;58' ,'3B2','563467'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'T;80' ,'2AN','d@g.com'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'T;88' ,'9LL','827120'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'T;88' ,'9LL','k@g.com'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'A;7;2','2AN','928233'

DECLARE @TableB  AS TABLE ( Customer  VARCHAR(100), Lab INT)
INSERT INTO @TableB
SELECT 'Lynn'      ,58 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Laurence'  ,80 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emmanuel'  ,88 


SELECT  b.Customer,
        b.Lab,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Entry)=1 THEN Entry END)As Tel,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Entry)<>1 THEN Entry END) AS Email 
FROM
(
SELECT  ParLab,
        Mcode,
        [Entry],
        CASE WHEN LEN(ParLab)-LEN(REPLACE(ParLab,';','')) = 1 
        THEN  SUBSTRING(ParLab,CHARINDEX(';', ParLab)+1,LEN(ParLab)) 
        ELSE NULL END AS Lab        
FROM @TableA 
) AS A
RIGHT JOIN @TableB B
ON a.Lab = b.Lab
GROUP BY b.Customer,b.Lab
```

Result

---

```
Customer    Lab Tel     Email
*******************************
Lynn        58  948487  e@y.com
Laurence    80  938745  d@g.com
Emmanuel    88  827120  k@g.com
```

Comment: I see you added to the original answer:  CASE WHEN LEN(ParLab)-LEN(REPLACE(ParLab,';','')) = 1 
        THEN  SUBSTRING(ParLab,CHARINDEX(';', ParLab)+1,LEN(ParLab)) 
        ELSE NULL END AS Lab

Comment: Smart move for null values