# String separation, column filtering to new columns and concatenation

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, concatenation, filtering

I have to extract value 'Lab' from ParLab in TableA. I am trying to filter from only the codes from 'Lab' that begin with 'L' and from 'Mcode' the ones that are correspond.

```
 TableA

 ParLab Mcode   Entry
 L;58   9LL     948487
 L;58   2AN     e@y.com
 L;80   9LL     938745
 L;58   3B2     563467
 T;80   2AN     d@g.com
 T;88   9LL     827120
 T;88   9LL     k@g.com
 A;47;2 2AN     928233
 L;80   2AN     d@m.com
```

Then I have to join on 'Lab' from TableB on the values separated from the string ParLab that correspond to 'Lab'.

```
  TableB

   Lab        Customer
   58         Lynn
   80         Laurence
   88         Emmanuel
```

The result should contain Tel and Email (concatenated if there is more than one value from TableA) in different columns assigned to 'Lab' and Customer joined to TableB on 'Lab'.

```
 Customer   Lab Tel               Email
 Lynn       58  948487, 563467    e@y.com
 Laurence   80  938745            d@g.com, d@m.com
 Emmanuel   88  827120            k@g.com
```

This is a variation from a previous post where the filter was meant only for some values for Mcode for the same customer.

[String separation and column filtering to new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096315/string-separation-and-column-filtering-to-new-columns?noredirect=1#comment102585445_58096315)

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: You should read database design books.  Your tables are recipes for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this different method-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[TableA]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TableA

CREATE TABLE TableA ( 
   ParLab varchar(10), 
   Mcode varchar(50),  
   Entry varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO TableA
   (ParLab, Mcode, Entry)
VALUES   
   ('L;58',   '9LL', '948487'),
   ('L;58',   '3B2', '563467'),
   ('L;58',   '2AN', 'e@y.com'),
   ('L;80',   '9LL', '938745'),
   ('T;80',   '2AN', 'd@g.com'),
   ('T;88',   '9LL', '827120'),
   ('L;80',   '2AN', 'd@m.com'),
   ('T;88',   '9LL', 'k@g.com'),
   ('A;47;2', '2AN', '928233')

IF OBJECT_ID('[TableB]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TableB

CREATE TABLE TableB ( 
   Customer varchar(50), 
   Lab varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO TableB
   (Customer, Lab)
VALUES   
   ('Lynn'   ,  58),
   ('Laurence', 80),
   ('Emmanuel', 88)

select c.customer,c.lab,
string_agg(case when charindex('@',p.entry)=0 then p.entry end,', ') as Tel,
string_agg(case when charindex('@',p.entry)>0 then p.entry end,', ') as Email
from TableA as p
inner join TableB as c
on ';' + p.[ParLab] +';' LIKE '%;' + cast(c.Lab as varchar) + ';%'
group by c.customer,c.lab
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to use `STRING_SPLIT()` and `STRING_AGG()` functions to split `ParLab` values and to aggregare data:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( 
   ParLab varchar(10), 
   Mcode varchar(50),  
   Entry varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO TableA
   (ParLab, Mcode, Entry)
VALUES   
   ('L;58',   '9LL', '948487'),
   ('L;58',   '3B2', '563467'),
   ('L;58',   '2AN', 'e@y.com'),
   ('L;80',   '9LL', '938745'),
   ('T;80',   '2AN', 'd@g.com'),
   ('T;88',   '9LL', '827120'),
   ('L;80',   '2AN', 'd@m.com'),
   ('T;88',   '9LL', 'k@g.com'),
   ('A;47;2', '2AN', '928233')
CREATE TABLE TableB ( 
   Customer varchar(50), 
   Lab varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO TableB
   (Customer, Lab)
VALUES   
   ('Lynn'   ,  58),
   ('Laurence', 80),
   ('Emmanuel', 88)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   b.Customer,
   b.Lab,
   STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('@', Entry) = 0 THEN Entry END, ',') AS Tel,
   STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('@', Entry) > 0 THEN Entry END, ',') AS Email
FROM TableA a
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(a.ParLab, ';') s
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON s.[value] = b.Lab
WHERE b.Customer IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY b.Customer, b.Lab
```

Results:

```
Customer    Lab Tel             Email
Lynn        58  948487,563467   e@y.com
Laurence    80  938745          d@g.com,d@m.com
Emmanuel    88  827120          k@g.com
```

Notes:

Function `STRING_SPLIT()` is available from SQL Server 2016, `STRING_AGG()` is available from SQL Server 2017+. Function `STRING_SPLIT()` should be used carefully, because the order of the returned rows is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.